What codes for the confetti in docker/welcome-to-docker?
I was recently impressed by the nuanced, physically realistic motion of the falling confetti in the confetti animation in the docker/welcome-to-docker image
used in the introductory tutorial by docker.
docker run -d -p 8080:80 docker/welcome-to-docker #then open http://localhost:8080

What is the code behind this confetti sim? How do I extract it?


They are using https://particles.js.org/

Note how the question isn't seeking a tutorial or recommendation for some library. It is about what the code/lib is in the first place or how to even go about finding it. Turns out, as NewByte states, the src. for the image is on Github and the lib they use is tsparticles. The question may be closed, but not for the currently stated reason.

@lineage It's pretty typical for questions to be closed even if they easily can answered just because they sort of kind of break a rule. I don't really get it, but I suspect that the verdict will be the same if I call a reopen vote.

The full source code for docker/welcome-to-docker can be found at the GitHub repo docker/welcome-to-docker. In particular, the particles are created using the tsParticles library as seen in src/Confetti.js.
